# toggle via data id not toggling back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that hides the `.wc-gallery` onload then toggles when a `p` with the same `data-id` is clicked. Now this script works only when you first toggle the `.wc-gallery`. When you are going to toggle it back to `hide()`, it will not work.

I have  multiple `.gallery-container2` declared in my HTML. Though it works fine when I have a currently active one, then click on another `p` from the other `.gallery-container2` it turns the `active` one to `hide()` then puts the recently clicked to `show()`.

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery-container2">
    <p data-id="1723"><strong>View before and after</strong></p>
    <div class="gallery-item" data-id="1723">
        <div class="wc-gallery" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
    $(window).load( function() { 
        $(".gallery-container2 .gallery-item .wc-gallery").hide();
    });
    $(".gallery-container2 p").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $(".gallery-container2").find('.gallery-item').each(function() {
            $(this).find('.wc-gallery').toggle($(this).data('id') === id);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your selector `$(".gallery-container2").find('.gallery-item')` is probably not specific enough since you stated there are multiple elements with that class on the page.  You could update it to either `$(this).find('.gallery-item')` or select on the data-id attribute using the id value you already found

Comment: pretty sure i can't be able to use `$(this).find('.gallery-item')` since I'm using the `.gallery-container2 p` it will not work, though if you can help change and add some additional structure to the script it would work somehow?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  `$("[data-id=" + id + "].gallery-item .wc-gallery").toggle()`

Comment: This would be another option https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Where should I put that one? better if you post that in the answer section not in the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the toggle definition as it doesn't take a predicate like you are passing it. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/    This will be more efficient as well as you won't have to iterate over each `.gallery-item`

```
$(".gallery-container2 p").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $("[data-id=" + id + "].gallery-item .wc-gallery").toggle()
});
```